# Using C++ to create Interface Panel with just UI file (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a UI file and want to create an Interface by Qt. I think having a UI file is enough to create a Interface Panel. and I want to do this job by a software programme which is created by myself, without open Qt. I want to do this work by a C++.

My UI file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>QtTabClass</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="QtTabClass">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>600</width>
<height>400</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>QtTab</string>
</property>
<widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
<widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>100</x>
<y>150</y>
<width>75</width>
<height>23</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="text">
<string>PushButton</string>
</property>
</widget>
</widget>
<widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>600</width>
<height>21</height>
</rect>
</property>
</widget>
<widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
<attribute name="toolBarArea">
<enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
</attribute>
<attribute name="toolBarBreak">
<bool>false</bool>
</attribute>
</widget>
<widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
</widget>
<layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
<resources>
<include location="qttab.qrc"/>
</resources>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

and I dont have other file and want to create an Interface screen.

Comment: Learn API of all the operating systems you want to maintain, then create a program that parse UI files and create all the windows and widgets using those API, and you will succeed!

Comment: "without open Qt"? You'll need some C++ at least to implement the logic.

Comment: @citi, seriously, what do you want and why? It's hard to understand your question

Comment: Questions probably should end in a question mark. And as I told you before, you can create your ui-file in any software you like, but the syntax and keywords have to be qt-specific if you want to use an QT-UI. Nevertheless you probably want to call qmake which will generate the code from your ui-xml-files.

Comment: How will you run Moc on the created file btw??

Comment: I create my UI file with other programmes and I can use the UI with QT without problem. I know that I need a programme which is produced by me. I do not want to open QT mauelly by myself. But I need to compile my Qt programme with my own UI file.

I want to run a C++ programme and it use a UI file (which I create before)(and I dont have any other files). The C++ programme compile Qt programme and then run the Interface panel.

Comment: I also add my UI file above. Thinks that I have just this UI file and I want to design an Interface Panel.

Comment: @citi, no, it's not clear even now. What do you mean by `I do not want to open QT mauelly by myself` and `I want to run a C++ programme and it use a UI file`? What do you mean by `QT`? Is it Qt library or some tool like QtDesigner?

Comment: I dont want to open Qt Creator by using Qt Icon, it will open automaticly with my C++ code. I want to compile it with a visual C++ programme.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel with this one. What is wrong with QtCreator and QtDesigner? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to do this project without any reason, but I want to learn how can I do it. I heard that it is possible. At least anyone know how can run QtDesigner with a code?İ(in a c++ code)